# MVC 4 Web Api Routing - Use relative path for routing URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

**Problem:**
I am trying to call the ApiController from localhost:xxxx/Home/TestPage and get a 404 that the Requested URL: /Home/api/Test cannot be found.

If I make this call from the Index.cshtml page it works fine and I can navigate to localhost:xxxx/api/Test and see the desired JSON.  I've tried adding ~/ to my MapHttpRoute routeTemplate but that throws an exception.

**Question:**
How do I remove /Home from the URL request?

Another example would be if I am on the page localhost:xxxx/People/TestPage and I want to hit multiple URIs such as localhost:xxxx/api/Hobbies, localhost:xxx/api/Pets and locahost:xxx/api/Vehicles.  How would I set up the custom routing to handle this?  As of right now with the default routes, I get the error that it can't find /People/api/Hobbies and so forth.

**SOLUTION (Possibly)**:
I created a custom MapHttpRoute with the routeTemplate: "{page}/api/{controller}/{id}" and it works but I don't completely understand WHY and if this is good practice or not.

Answer (score 0):

Home is your default **HTTP** controller.  Home/api/Test is not a valid Web API controller route unless you have created custom routes. The out of the box default web api route is `api/{controller}/{id}`.  So, if you had an API controller called home, it's URL would be localhost/api/home/id

Comment: I'm still confused.  How could I create the custom route?  Right now the .cshtml file is in the Home directory in Views.  I'm trying to access TestController but get the error I listed.  I tried changing my routeTemplate to "~/api/{controller}/{id}" but that threw an exception.

Comment: Is the test controller an API controller or an HTTP controller?